# How to sum largest values in column up to certain percentage in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, percentage

How can I sum the largest values in a column up to a certain percentage or number? I was trying to somehow use SUM() and SUMIF() with LARGE(), but I haven't been able to figure it out. Ideally, I would like to be able to do this without having to sort the column in descending order since this formula will be applied to multiple columns.

Comment: Changing the question after getting answers is considered bad form on this site.  It makes the people who answered prior to the change look like they do not know what they are doing and opens them up to being down voted.  Clarifications are okay but changing the very question is wrong.

Comment: Okay... So everyone knows, I did add to the question to clarify what I was looking for since my original post did not state what I was actually trying to accomplish. I wasn't trying to offend or make anyone look bad. Thanks for the input.

Comment: The change should be a new question, not a amendment to the existing one.  This question should be rolled back to the original.  And If any below answered the original it should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Data is in cells `A1:A20`

Limit number is in cell B1, some possible formulas:

```
{=SUM(A1:A20*--(A1:A20>B1))}
=SUMIF(A1:A20;">"&B1;A1:A20)
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A20;--(A1:A20>B1))
```

Limit % is in cell B2, some possible formulas:

```
={SUM(A1:A20*--(A1:A20>MAX(A1:A20)*B2))}
=SUMIF(A1:A20;">"&(B2*MAX(A1:A20));A1:A20)
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A20;--(A1:A20>B2*MAX(A1:A20)))
```

(`{...}` are array formulas, use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: Why use CSE, when changing the SUM to SUMPRODUCT will do the same without the CSE?

Comment: Yes will do that same, just added these for info.

Answer (score 0):

To find the top percentage use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$F$10)*(PERCENTRANK.INC($F$1:$F$10,$F$1:$F$10)>0.7))
```

Where $F$1:$F$10 is your data set.  And .7 is the lower threshold.

To find the top nth number:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE($F$1:$F$10,ROW(1:5)))
```

Change the 5 to the number of largest numbers to sum. So this will sum the largest 5 numbers.

To sum everything over a certain number:

```
=SUMIF($F$1:$F$10,">=" & 10)
```

Where 10 is the lower threshold.